# Qt Creator: как различать debug и release из проекта?

Tags: qtcreator, qmake

В pro-файле нужно указать разные настройки для debug и release конфигурации. Почитал документацию, вроде как утверждается, что нужно использовать named scopes debug и release. Я сделал небольшой тестовый проект такого вида:

```
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp

message(===Run config===)
debug {
    message(===Debug===)
    SOURCES += debug.cpp
}

release {
    message(===Release===)
    SOURCES += release.cpp
}
```

В файлах debug.cpp и release.cpp опрделена одна и та же фунция.

Открываю проект в Qt Creator, настраиваю проект для сборки с использованием MinGW, выбираю конфигурацию Debug, запускаю сборку - в результате в консоли вижу:

```
Project MESSAGE: ===Run config===
Project MESSAGE: ===Debug===
Project MESSAGE: ===Release===
Project MESSAGE: ===Run config===
Project MESSAGE: ===Debug===
Project MESSAGE: ===Release===
Project MESSAGE: ===Run config===
Project MESSAGE: ===Debug===
Project MESSAGE: ===Release===
```

Конфигурирование выполняется три раза, причём на каждом разе включена одновременно и дебаговая и релизная конфигурации. Как следствие в проект включаются одновременно оба файла и на этапе линковки получаем сообщение об ошибке:

```
Src\build-qmake-test-Desktop_Qt_5_12_3_MinGW_64_bit-Debug/../qmake-test/release.cpp:4: multiple definition of `printMessage()'
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чём тут дело? Может быть я что-то делаю не так? Какой правильный способ определять релизная сейчас конфигурация или дебаговая?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже я нашёл решение. Оно [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19562591/qt-creator-config-debug-release-switches-does-not-work). Оказывается это баг не то в qmake, не то в Qt Creator. Нужно писать так:

```
CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
    message(===Debug===)
    SOURCES += debug.cpp
}

CONFIG(release, debug|release) {
    message(===Release===)
    SOURCES += release.cpp
}
```

Причём открывающая фигурная скобка должна быть на той же строке что и конструкция CONFIG. Иначе выражение будет всегда считаться как TRUE.

Comment: QTCreator возможно под win включает режим CONFIG+=debug_and_release поэтому у Вас qmake вызывается  дважды подробнее тут читал http://blog.mgsxx.com/?p=2140

Comment: Что касается открывающейся скобки, это особенность синтаксиса qmake см 'Scopes' https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-language.html#scopes